# Query de SQL para filtrar 2 columnas

Tags: c#, sql, datatables

Quería preguntar como puedo filtrar dos columnas de una base de datos a la vez, ejemplo:

```
| id| nombre |  fecha    |
|123|  asd   | 3/12/2019 |
|122|  asd   | 3/12/2019 |
|121|  fse   | 3/12/2019 |
|120|  fsf   | 3/12/2019 |
```

por ejemplo yo querría el resultado de la siguiente forma:

```
| id| nombre |  fecha    |
|123|  asd   | 3/12/2019 |
|121|  fse   | 3/12/2019 |
```

Los últimos 2 Nombres diferentes ingresados.

Este Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PCBRESULT.PCBNAME 
FROM PCBRESULT 
GROUP BY PCBRESULT.PCBNAME 
ORDER BY PCBRESULT.PCBNAME DESC
```

No me funciono ya que me arroja todos los datos de la tabla. Probé con el TOP 2 pero mismo resultado me arroja los últimos 2 pero los acomoda de acuerdo al ID No. y creo que en este caso debería ser por nombre, solo que de igual forma me da los resultados organizandolos de forma alfabética

alguna ayuda por favor

Comment: que has intentado hasta ahora??... Por favor ve a [ask] para mas informacion

Comment: Este Query `SELECT DISTINCT PCBRESULT.PCBNAME FROM PCBRESULT GROUP BY PCBRESULT.PCBNAME ORDER BY PCBRESULT.PCBNAME DESC` No me funciono ya que me arroja todos los datos de la tabla. Proble con el TOP 2 pero mismo resultado me arroja los ultimos 2 pero los acomoda de acuerdo al ID No. y creo que en este caso deberia ser por nombre, solo que de igual forma me da los resultados organizandolos de forma alfabetica

Comment: La información de la pregunta se añade editando la pregunta, no en los comentarios. :) De paso, si añades los nombres reales de la tabla, sería más fácil ayudarte a corregir tu query

Comment: Muchas gracias, Alfabravo. Hice la pregunta de la siguiente manera para hacerlo mas facil en cuanto a respuesta y poder entenderlo mejor, lo siento.

Answer (score 0):

Es un poco confusa tu pregnta pero en general para hacer filtros desde SQL tienes la sentencia `where` por ejemplo: `SELECT PCBRESULT.PCBNAME FROM PCBRESULT WHERE ID = 123` Lo cual te daria como resultado solo la columna que tenga ese ID

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, mi tabla se actualiza cada cierto tiempo por eso ocupo los ultimos id y me interesa filtrar los nombres para tener los ultimos dos en cuenta, asi entren 100 nombres (ABC) y 5 (DEF) quiero que me muestre 'abc id 105'  y 'def ID 5' me explico? lo siento por no ser tan especifico en mi pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo tienes las 3 columnas y buscas el último ID de cada combinación de nombre y fecha, sólo necesitas usar una función de agregado.

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS id,
       nombre,
       fecha
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY nombre,
         fecha;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta de más que pongas el **GROUP BY**,
o sea, solo deberías de tener tu query así:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 pcbname, fecha
FROM pcbresult
ORDER BY fecha DESC
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, probe con este query pero al momento de acomodar el pcbname lo hace, pero alfabeticamente, asi que solo pondria el asd y fse por el orden alfabetico, no porque los ordene, osea si le agrego un valor aun mas abajo (asr por ejemplo) me lo pondria antes que el fse

Comment: Ah, ok, entonces tendrías que ordenar por fecha "ORDER BY fecha" (ya actualicé el query). Pero para que no tengas problemas, tu fecha debería tener FECHA Y HORA